# What is the complete list of way to show a View Controller which invokes the view lifecycle (viewDidAppear etc)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know the complete list of public apple factory methods that will show a view controller and invoke the view lifecycle.

1. viewDidLoad
2. viewWillAppear
3. viewDidAppear
4. viewWillDissapear
5. viewDidDissapear
6. viewDidUnload

Here are the ones I am aware of:

**`UINavigationController`**

- `setViewControllers:animated:`
- `pushViewController:animated:`
- `popViewControllerAnimated:`
- `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`
- `popToViewController:animated:`

**`UITabBarController`**

- `selectedViewController`  (property)
- `setViewControllers:animated:`

**`UIViewController`**

- `presentModalViewController:animated:`
- `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

Are there any I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `-(void)awakeFromNib` should be one.